# Kernel IP routing table with all 0's

Tags: ubuntu, routing

Running Ubuntu 14.04 Linux kernel.

```
Kernel IP routing table 
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         134.8.2.126         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     1003   0        0 wlan0
```

What does the second line signify with all of the `0.0.0.0`'s?

Comment: What operating system is this?

Comment: have updated the post.